# using underscore js to duplicate list items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

i have a json with some dates that looks like this for example

```
jsonEvents = [
    {'event_name':'event1','event_start':'2013-10-23','event_stop':'2013-10-29'},
    {'event_name':'event2','event_start':'2013-10-23','event_stop':'2013-10-25'}
];
```

i want to use underscoreJS to cut this events into half (just to make the idea more simple). What i want as output would look like this.

```
jsonEvents = [
    {'event_name':'event1','event_start':'2013-10-23','event_stop':'2013-10-26'},
    {'event_name':'event1','event_start':'2013-10-26','event_stop':'2013-10-29'},
    {'event_name':'event2','event_start':'2013-10-23','event_stop':'2013-10-24'},
    {'event_name':'event2','event_start':'2013-10-24','event_stop':'2013-10-25'}
];
```

I hope i can do this in a simple way, i am working on an angularJS project and i hope underscoreJS class can do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it have to be a deep copy (different variables) or can it be the same reference?

Comment: i have a copy of it. i used $scope.jsonEvents = angular.copy($scope.jsonOriginalEvents);

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of `concatMap` for this, which Underscore does not offer. You might either use jQuery's [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) which does this, or build it yourself:

```
var concatMap = _.compose(_.flatten, _.map);
```

Now, you can iterate over your array and return an array of two events for each item:

```
function createEvent(name, start, end) {
    return {
        "event_name": name,
        "event_start": format(start),
        "event_stop": format(end)
    };
}
jsonEvents = concatMap(jsonEvents, function (event) {
    var from = new Date(event.event_start),
        to = new Date(event.event_stop),
        mid = new Date( (+startDate + stopDate) / 2 );
    return [
        createEvent(event.event_name, from, mid),
        createEvent(event.event_name, mid, to)
    ];
});
```